# Stop jasmine test after first expect fails

Tags: jasmine

I'm familiar with python unittest tests where if an assertion fails, that test is marked as "failed" and it moves on to other tests. Jasmine on the other hand will continue through all expects even if the one of them fails. How can I make Jasmine stop processing a test after the first expectation fails?

```
it ("shouldn't need to test other expects if the first fails", function() {
    expect(array.length).toBe(1);

    // don't need to check this if the first failed.
    expect(array[0]).toBe("foo");
});
```

Am I thinking about it wrong? I have some tests with lots of `expect`'s and it seems like a waste to show all the stack traces when only the first is wrong really.

Comment: If you have so much asserts per test, your code is testing too much each time. It may be easier to develop this way, but it is much harder to know where the problem is when the tests fail in the future (also, it kind of is the point of tests, no? To tell the future developer s/he created a bug). I kind of find it useful that Jasmine doesnt stop on the first expect, it shows everything went wrong instead of what went wrong first. Anyway, as for the question per se, I have looked a bit and haven't found anything to make it quit after the first fail.

Comment: Keep in mind though that in this particular example, the first assertion (array length) is redundant: you don't _need_ to check the exact array length if you are then also checking the exact elements anyways (because it's inherently implied by how arrays work). In JS, the only exception to this is when an array's length is set manually and thus it gets padded with `undefined` elements, in which case you could either assert that none of the elements are `undefined`, or that the array's length is not _greater_ than a specific number. This way, assertions will complete each other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Gregg's answer was correct for the latest version of Jasmine at that time ([v2.0.0](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases/tag/v2.0.0)).

However, since then, this new feature was [added](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/release_notes/2.3.0.md#pull-requests--issues) in [v2.3.0](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases/tag/v2.3.0):

> Allow user to stop a specs execution when an expectation fails (Fixes [#577](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/577))

It's activated by adding `throwFailures=true` to the query string of the runner page, eg:

```
http://localhost:8000/?throwFailures=true
```

Comment: To use the new feature in node.js, set `"stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": true` on the top level of `jasmine.json` or run `jasmine --stop-on-failure=true` (confusing just `--stop-on-failure` is silently ignored).  If given, flag overrides config.

Comment: @beni-cherniavsky-paskin @tachyonvortex but using `stopSpecOnExpectationOnFailure` stops the entire set of tests... there is a way to *ONLY* stop a single `it` (test)?

Answer (score 8):

Jasmine doesn't support failing early, in a single spec. The idea is to give you all of the failures in case that helps figure out what is really wrong in your spec.

Comment: What do you suggest in situations like OPs? Should we check with an if after expect(array.length).toBe(1); and return early?

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine has stop on failure feature and you can check it here:
https://plnkr.co/plunk/Ko5m6MQz9VUPMMrC

This starts jasmine with `oneFailurePerSpec` property.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments of https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/414 I figured out that 2 solutions exists for this:
https://github.com/radialanalytics/protractor-jasmine2-fail-whale
https://github.com/Updater/jasmine-fail-fast

I just started to use the protractor-jasmine2-fail-whale because it seems to have more features. Although to take screenshots in case of test failures I currently use protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jasmine in Appium (a tool to test React Native apps).

I fixed the issue by adding `stopSpecOnExpectationFailure=true` to Jasmine configs

jasmine v3.8.0 & jasmine-core v3.8.0