# How to stop protractor from running further testcases on failure?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

Is there a way of quitting test suite and stop executing further test cases, if a test case fails in protractor?

Comment: Which test runner framework are you using in protractor?  ("jasmine" is the default)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In case of `jasmine` testing framework, you are not the first asking about it.

There are relevant open discussions/issues on exiting after a first failure, `--fail-fast` option:

- [Bail on first failure](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/414)
- [--fail-fast option?](https://github.com/johnbintz/jasmine-headless-webkit/issues/114)
- [Please add --fail-fast support](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/16)

Long story short, this is an open issue and some day `jasmine` would have the functionality built-in. Currently, use a third-party [`jasmine-bail-fast`](https://github.com/goodeggs/jasmine-bail-fast) module.

Aside from that, there is a handy `realtimeFailure` jasmine setting. If you set it to `true` it would not fail the whole test run, but it would show errors in a real time - immediately after happening - this can possibly cover your use case. Set it in `jasmineNodeOpts`:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',

    ...

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        realtimeFailure: true
    }
}
```

Comment: According to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119193/stop-jasmine-test-after-first-expect-fails jasmine now has the feature as of 2.3.0.  In a comment to http://stackoverflow.com/a/31809311/571380 the person mentions `stopSpecOnExpectationFailure` to be put in the config. However, I tried `exports.config = { ..., jasmineNodeOpts: { stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: true } }` in my conf.js file and that did not work for me.

Comment: @Machtyn could you please create a separate question and let's see if this is built-in now and works? Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe Thanks and done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334069/protractor-jasmine-and-stopping-test-on-first-fail

Answer (score 11):

Here is my solution to skip tests on first fail with Jasmine 2 and Protractor.
Hope it helps.

```
exports.config = {
    onPrepare: function () {
        //skip tests after first fail
        var specs = [];
        var orgSpecFilter = jasmine.getEnv().specFilter;
        jasmine.getEnv().specFilter = function (spec) {
            specs.push(spec);
            return orgSpecFilter(spec);
        };
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new function () {
            this.specDone = function (result) {
                if (result.failedExpectations.length > 0) {
                    specs.forEach(function (spec) {
                        spec.disable()
                    });
                }
            };
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I only succeeded with your version. "protractor-fail-fast" and "realtimeFailure: true" did not work for me.

Comment: it is not working -Can you give some sample decribe block with thi

Answer (score 9):

`jasmine-bail-fast` didn't work in my case. Not sure if it was because of some conflicts with my other report plugins.

In case anyone is having the same problem. You can try [protractor-fast-fail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-fail-fast)

```js
import failFast from 'protractor-fail-fast';

exports.config = {
  // if import statement doesn't work, use this instead of import for older versions of node
  // plugins: [{
  //  package: 'protractor-fail-fast'
  // }],

  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
  },

  afterLaunch: function() {
    failFast.clean(); 
  }  
}
```

Worked perfectly well for me.

*EDIT: added import statement in code snippet to reflect readme of projactor-fast-fail*

Comment: same here, for me also bail-fast did't work but protractor-fast-fail worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi i am getting ReferenceError: failFast is not defined

Comment: @PDHide check their npm/github page. Plugin import seem to be changed. Add this line `import failFast from 'protractor-fail-fast';` at the start of your file. *(it's a good practice to not just copy code from stackoverflow, instead try to use it as a reference)*

Comment: @LinhPham I am using JavaScript , and import fsilfsst from shows syntax error

Answer (score 4):

you don't need all those third party plugins. Use native `process.exit()`.

Code example:

```
it("test", function()
{
   ...
   if(isExit)
   {
      browser.driver.close().then(function()
      {
         process.exit(1);
      });
   }
});
```

profit.

Comment: Is this 100% correct way to exit? I.e. will this call all jasmine and protractor clean-up functions, so everything is closed properly?

Comment: No it will not. It just stops the server process