# Protractor, Jasmine, and stopping test on first fail

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node

While trying to figure out how to make certain jasmine expect statements dependent on a previous expect statement I discovered that previous to Jasmine 2.3.0, there was not a way. (see [Stop jasmine test after first expect fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119193/stop-jasmine-test-after-first-expect-fails))  However, Jasmine 2.3.0 added an option `stopSpecOnExpectationFailure` that when set to true will stop a test on the first failure.

Excited by this prospect, I modified my conf.js to include the option:

```
/*
 * conf.js
 */
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['search-spec.js'],
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: true
    }
};
```

But this did not work for me.

In my test, I have:

```
/**
 * Test option from select element is selected
 */
function verifyOptionSelected(option) {
   var myEl = $('select[value="' + option + '"]';

   expect(myEl.isPresent()).toBe(true, 'Option, ' + option + ', is not a value in the dropdown list. (It might be the text.)');

   expect(myEl.isSelected()).toBe(true, 'Option, ' + option + ', is not selected as expected.');
}
```

In the code above, both expect statements will be attempted, but I don't need the second to be attempted if the first fails.

Are there any of you who have figured this out with jasmine?

(Yes, I know about [jasmine-bail-fast](https://github.com/goodeggs/jasmine-bail-fast) and [protractor-fail-fast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-fail-fast). However, in my opinion, using the built-in feature is a better solution.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I see in the `protractor` and [`jasmine-npm`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm) (the jasmine runner that `protractor` uses) source code, it is not as simple as adding the `stopSpecOnExpectationFailure` or `stopOnFailure` jasmine node option to the configuration. There has to be changes applied to `protractor` to support the new `stopSpecOnExpectationFailure` jasmine node option. Please create an issue/feature request in [`Protractor` issue tracker](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues).

---

I've also tried to call the `throwOnExpectationFailure` function, set the `stopSpecOnExpectationFailure` value throw `jasmine.getEnv()` in `onPrepare()` but none of that worked. Perhaps, I am missing something and there is a way to enable the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `npm install protractor-fail-fast`

Then in **protractor.conf.js**

```
const failFast = require('protractor-fail-fast');

...
exports.config = {
  plugins: [
    failFast.init(),
  ],
  afterLaunch: function () {
    failFast.clean(); // Removes the fail file once all test runners have completed.
  },
}
```

[image]