# Protractor test hangs on await browser.wait with disabled control flow

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-e2e

We're writing e2e tests in async/await fashion to be able to debug them. But test that has

```
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(appPage.getLogo()));
```

Just hangs on this line. I don't know why and I don't get it. It runs fine when control flow is enabled but as soon as we disable it, it starts hanging. The test case looks like this

```
it('should login', async () => {
    await page.navigateTo();
    await page.login();
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(appPage.getLogo()));
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/login');
  });
```

Idea is to wait for navigation to be complete after we login. In browser where I can see e2e execution it is clearly visible that it reached the right page and the logo is there, but it gets stuck there until timeout happens. Does anyone know why?

Comment: This this:         
       var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
        browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(currentURL){   
            if (currentURL == baseUrl+'/login') {
                clearInterval(checkExist);
            }
        })  
        }, 1000); // check every 1000ms

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get the scenario straight:

You await for a login, and when this step is done it shows a logo on a different page right?
If that's the case then I might guess the issue.
Lets say that the function login() is done, before it is able to render the logo in the DOM it already runs the app.Page.getLogo().
So you have a scenario like;

Login() then 
renders logo then
getLogo()

So you have a complexity of finding the rendering time from page1 -> page 2. This is not a constant time. So what you want to is to have something which runs a code and check for a specif element multiple times, in the DOM.

I'm not sure how your test has been made to check if the logo is available or not in the page, but I would recommend you to look for a id tag in the DOM.

Just to see if it your await function works, make a timeout after you call
await page.login(); and see what happens, Set the timeout to 30 seconds just check.

So Usually when its about page rendering you would probably need a sleep timer which checks if the element on the next page is there (element of your logon-logo etc.)

A code reference would be;

[wait for complete page load does not work as expected in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564748/wait-for-complete-page-load-does-not-work-as-expected-in-protractor)

Comment: you're right, I tried adding timeout before waiting for element to be present.
but in this case I have a question: how do I wait until new page is rendered after login? is there good way to check without setting a timeout?