# JsTestDriver on NetBeans stops testing after a failed assertion

Tags: javascript, netbeans, js-test-driver

I have set up JavaScript unit testing with JS Test Driver on Netbeans as per [this Link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-js-support.html#jstestdriver). However, unlike the results in that tutorial, no more tests are executed after an assertion fails. How can I change this behaviour?

For example, given this test file:

The `test.js` file:

```
AssertionsTestCase = TestCase("AssertionsTestCase");

AssertionsTestCase.prototype.testAlwaysPass = function(){
  assertEquals(1, 1);
  assertEquals(2, 2);
};
AssertionsTestCase.prototype.testAlwaysFail1 = function(){
  assertEquals(1, 2);
};
AssertionsTestCase.prototype.testAlwaysFail2 = function(){
  assertEquals(3, 4);
};
```

the progress bar shows 50%, (2 tests), it should say 33%.

[image]

The `jsTestDriver.conf` file:

```
server: http://localhost:42442
load:
  - test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js
  - test/lib/jasmine-jstd-adapter/JasmineAdapter.js
  - test/unit/*.js
```

---

I can have all tests run by command line. (On Windows PowerShell). Running as follows, tests do not stop running after a failure:

---

> java -jar $env:JSTD\JsTestDriver-1.3.5.jar --tests all --config jsTestDriver.conf

the `jsTestDriver.conf` file:

```
server: http://localhost:4244
load:
  - test/lib/jasmine/jasmine.js
  - test/lib/jasmine-jstd-adapter/JasmineAdapter.js
  - test/unit/*.js
```

All three tests are run.

Comment: Did you try it with another browser?
Since it is working from the command line, I assume the failure is caused by netbeans or the browser.

Comment: will this help you? jasmine --stop-on-failure=false  https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/node.html#section-21

Comment: Maybe the comments here can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119193/stop-jasmine-test-after-first-expect-fails

Comment: I think netbeans test handling is buggy, at least with Mocha.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like in Chrome works fine.
[image]

Regarding Firefox as in comment said it is not correct answer. I have managed to get it work partially. The issue is how netbeans handle failed tests and how jstestdriver.jar is started. I know this doesn't solve issue but it is pointing in right direction.

[image]

Steps to reproduce this.

1. Start JS Test Driver from Services
2. Run test.
3. Since I am using linux. I have located jstestdriver.properties from Netbeans configuration folder for current user. In my case it is located in

   `/home/{user}/.netbeans/8.2/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/javascript/jstestdriver.properties`

   Edit location property by adding arguments to jstestdriver.jar --tests all --reset. After editing my properties looks like this.

   `location=/home/user/Downloads/jstestdriver-1.3.5.jar --tests all --reset
   server.url=http://localhost:42442
   strict.mode=false
   use.browser.ANDROID_DEVICE_CHROME=false
   use.browser.ANDROID_DEVICE_DEFAULT=false
   use.browser.ANDROID_EMULATOR_DEFAULT=false
   use.browser.Chrome=false
   use.browser.Chrome.INTEGRATED=false
   use.browser.SL__Browsers_FirefoxBrowser=true
   use.browser.SL__Browsers_MozillaBrowser=false`
4. Repeat 2 times.

   - Restart JS Test Driver from Services.
   - Run test.

After second restart and run, it should run all tests as in picture above. If you can add arguments --tests all --reset for JS Test Driver in Netbeans it should solve issue to work as in Chrome.