# In jasmine stop execution after any test fails?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, automated-tests

I know there are lot of chains having same question asked and answered. But can any one answer for naive developers?

I have a java script code to be tested using jasmine and my each suit will have 7-10 test cases dependent on each there. For example:
1st case : expect user name and password entered
2nd case : login successful.

So if 1st case fails then it should not execute 2nd test case. it should stop execution. (it is just a dummy example i have given).

Is there any way in jasmine that will check if any test case is fail then exit suit and do not execute further test cases? (There are ways like *stopSpecOnExpectationFailure* and may be others.)

Appreciate if it can be explained in simple terms with examples so any one can use it as tutorials.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using version 2.3.0 or above, you may pass parms to script runner like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119193/stop-jasmine-test-after-first-expect-fails)

Comment: @WinterSoldier i tried that, it didn't work. Tried it on chrome browser with one simple math function.