# how to do stop jasmine unit testing if any one of the test is failed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, command

I wrote above 500 unit test methods. when i give `ng test` command. it starting to test all the 500 methods.

If any test cases failed, it wont stop and still it continue to execute all methods. So i need wait more time to rerun the unit test again.

I know we can exist  by  doing `ctr+c`  and again rerun the unit test by using `ng test` command. This way also taking too much time.

So is it possible to stop (not exist)  the unit test, if any one of the test is failed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [stop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22119193/1265945) jasmine test after first expect fails.

The answer is found inside that question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31809311/1265945).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop jasmine test after first expect fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119193/stop-jasmine-test-after-first-expect-fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude the file from the all test cases. try to add in the exclude section in the cli config file.

```
src/tsconfig.app.json:
```

shown here:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "filename.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `fdescribe` in `jasmine` library. Its exactly same as the jasmine  `describe` function except that by using this function karma (if you'r using karma) executed only `fdescribe` blocks and ignore all `describe` blocks, for example :

```
fdescribe('this block will executed' , async()=>{ 
 ....
 it('only this method will during tests', ()=>{
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
 });
...
describe('this block not executed' ()=>{
   .....
}
```

when tests finish you can simply repalce `fdescribe` function with `describe`