# Failing all tests in a protractor file if BeforeAll failes

Tags: protractor

I have a protractor test with the following beforeAll code:

```
beforeAll(async (done: Function) => {
  await browser.restart();
  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  await performLogin('/some_url', LOGIN_EMAIL, LOGIN_PASSWORD);
  await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
  done();
});
```

The login page is Microsoft Azure Ad, which isn't angular, hence the need to disable `waitForAngular()`.

Sometimes it fails (a problem I am working on). However, when it fails the tests all run, and of course time out because they end up on the login screen.

Is there something I can call in beforeAll() to say "fail every scenario here"?

Comment: Do you mean do not run 'It' blocks if beforeAll() fails?

Comment: @vin yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 1):

There's `protractor-fail-fast`, you can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-fail-fast). It basically exits on the first failure, instead of trying to run all tests.

A solution to your particular situation would then be to have the end of your `beforeAll()` run a verification that the URL is past the login page, something like:

`expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).not.toContain('microsoft.com/login')`

If that fails, Protractor will exit right there.

To answer the question in general, you're not the first to [be looking for this type of functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119193/stop-jasmine-test-after-first-expect-fails/31809311#31809311) and the Protractor devs [are aware of it](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3234) given that Jasmine now supports it, but it doesn't look like the issue has moved much.